# How do we define optional keywords for a function?

Tags: python, function

I have a question about how do we define **optional** keywords when we write a **function**. Also how do we determine keywords that it would be required if another condition satisfied, for instance, the keyword `make_plot` would be `True` then the user needs to provide `plot_dir` keyword for that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have complex logic for determining which keyword arguments are required and which are optional, it's best to simply accept *arbitrary* keyword arguments using

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
```

(`kwargs` is simply conventional; the name can be anything, as long as it is prefixed with `**` and appears *after* all other arguments).

Now that your function will accept any argument, you can process them inside your function. Here is an example which will

- reject any keyword arguments other than `a`, `b`, or `c`
- Makes `a` a required argument
- Makes `b` optional
- If `b` is `True`, then `c` must be an integer between 1 and 10; otherwise, `c` is ignored

Her is the function

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
    try:
        a_value = kwargs.pop('a')
    except KeyError:            
        raise TypeError("Missing required keyword argument 'a'")

    b_value = kwargs.pop(b, False)
    if b_value is True:
        try:
            c_value = int(kwargs.pop('c'))
            if not (1 <= c_value <= 10):
                raise ValueError
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError("Must use keyword argument 'c' if 'b' is True")
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("'c' must be an integer between 1 and 10!")

    try:
        # Are there anymore keyword arguments? We don't care which one we get
        x = next(iter(kwargs))
    except StopIteration:
        # Good, nothing besides a, b, or c
        pass
    else:
        raise TypeError("Unrecognized keyword argument '{0}'".format(x))

    # Now do what my_function is supposed to with a_value, b_value, c_value
```

---

To address your comment, imagine a simple function which only checks for `plot_dir` if `make_plot` is found. (We're being more lax, because we will just ignore `plot_dir` if `make_plot` is missing, rather than flagging its use as an error.)

```
def plot(**kwargs):
    if 'make_plot' in kwargs:
        plot_dir = kwargs.get('plot_dir', "/default/plot/dir")
        # save or otherwise process the value of kwargs['make_plot']
```

Comment: How should your example look like if both `make_plot` and `plot_dir` will be optional but `plot_dir` would be related to the decision about `make_plot`?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, take a look at the [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

For your second question, that's not how you do it. Make `plot_dir` an optional argument that defaults to `None` and check whether `plot_dir is not None` at the start of the function.

```
def plot(plot_dir=None):
    if plot_dir is not None:  # an argument was provided
        do_some_plots(plot_dir)
    else:
        do_something_else()
```